# Adding pre-defined static SVG to a Leaflet map doesn't work

Tags: svg, leaflet

I need to add a control that contains several pre-defined svg elements. They display the contours of regions that are off-shore to Europe. They have different zoom levels.
Hovering over the main country should highlight the corresponding off-shore regions. Clicking on one of them moves the main map to that region. Other than this, no extra behaviour is required.

The SVG does however not render. I class the SVG-control using L.Control.extend:

```
    L.Insets = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'bottomleft'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this._insets = {
            "FR93":{translate: {x: 118, y:-485}, paths:["M-66 513L-76 531L-80 535L-89 533L-94 536L-99 533L-95 529L-93 521L-97 513L-98 504L-91 494L-81 498L-68 507L-66 512z"]},
            "FR91_2":{translate: {x: 192, y:-353}, paths:["M-177 373L-178 370L-175 372L-177 373z", "M-179 375L-180 376L-180 371L-179 375z","M-173 394L-174 389L-170 393L-171 394z"]}
        }
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        // create a DOM element and put it into one of the map panes
        this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'wt-inset-pane');

        for (var id in this._insets) {
            var inset = L.DomUtil.create("div", "inset", this._container);
            inset.id = id;
            var svg = L.DomUtil.create("svg", "", inset);
            svg.setAttribute("width", "100");
            svg.setAttribute("height", "100");
            var g = L.DomUtil.create("g", "", svg);
            for (var i=0,l=this._insets[id].paths.length; i < l; i++) {
                var path = L.DomUtil.create("path", "", g);
                path.setAttribute("style", "transform: translate(" + this._insets[id].translate.x + "px, " + this._insets[id].translate.y + "px);");
                path.setAttribute("stroke-linejoin", "round");
                path.setAttribute("stroke-linecap", "round");
                path.setAttribute("fill-rule", "evenodd");
                path.setAttribute("stroke", "#808080");
                path.setAttribute("stroke-opacity", "1");
                path.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1");
                path.setAttribute("fill", "#FFFFFF");
                path.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "1");
                path.setAttribute("d", this._insets[id].paths[i]);
            }
        }
        return this._container;
    }
});

L.insets = function () {
    return new L.Insets();
};
```

I instantiate the class using `map.addControl(L.insets());`

Everything is inserted corectly but the SVG doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Your "g" need a style "transform" too ^^

```js
L.Insets = L.Control.extend({
    
    options: {
 position: 'bottomright'
    },

    initialize: function() {
 this._insets = {
     
     // FRANCE
     
     "FR93":{translate: {x: 118, y:-485}, paths:["M-66 513L-76 531L-80 535L-89 533L-94 536L-99 533L-95 529L-93 521L-97 513L-98 504L-91 494L-81 498L-68 507L-66 512z"]},
     "FR91_2":{translate: {x: 192, y:-353}, paths:["M-177 373L-178 370L-175 372L-177 373z", "M-179 375L-180 376L-180 371L-179 375z","M-173 394L-174 389L-170 393L-171 394z"]},
     "FR94":{translate:{x:-770, y:-979}, paths:["M790 1011L785 1009L786 1005L788 1005L791 1008L790 1011z"]},
     
     // PORTUGAL
     
     "PT20":{translate:{x:522,y:-443},paths:["M-440 484L-430 484L-434 487L-442 487L-446 483L-445 482L-440 484z","M-498 467L-500 468L-507 466L-507 464L-504 463L-496 467L-498 467z","M-474 460L-478 460L-481 457L-475 457L-473 459L-474 460z","M-492 462L-490 463L-497 461L-502 457L-494 460z","M-511 464L-514 461L-510 461L-510 464z"]},
     "PT30":{translate:{x:262,y:-595},paths:["M-242 628L-246 628L-251 624L-249 622L-246 624L-243 623L-239 625L-239 627L-241 628z"]},
     
     // ESPAGNE
     
     "ES70":{translate:{x:641,y:-960},paths:["M-612 995L-616 991L-607 988L-607 990L-611 994z","M-586 995L-588 995L-585 993L-583 987L-581 986L-581 993L-586 995z","M-601 999L-603 996L-602 994L-599 994L-599 998z","M-579 984L-581 985L-576 980L-576 982L-579 984z","M-626 989L-628 986L-627 985L-625 988L-626 989z","M-618 994L-619 996L-620 993L-618 994z","M-627 1000L-630 999L-627 998L-627 1000z"]}
     
 }
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
     
 this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-insets');
               
 var xHTML = '';

 for (var id in this._insets) {

     var pathx = this._insets[id].translate.x;
     var pathy = this._insets[id].translate.y;

     xHTML += '<div id="'+id+'" class="inset">';
     xHTML += '<svg>';
     xHTML += '<g style="transform: translate('+pathx+'px,'+pathy+'px)">';

     for (var i=0,l=this._insets[id].paths.length; i < l; i++) {
  xHTML += '<path d="'+ this._insets[id].paths[i] +'" ';
  xHTML += ' class="leaflet-clickable" ';
  xHTML += ' fill-opacity="1" ';
  xHTML += ' fill="#FFFFFF" ';
  xHTML += ' stroke-width="1" ';
  xHTML += ' stroke-opacity="1" ';
  xHTML += ' stroke="#808080" ';
  xHTML += ' fill-rule="evenodd" ';
  xHTML += ' stroke-linecap="round" ';
  xHTML += ' stroke-linejoin="round" ';
  xHTML += '/>';
     }

     xHTML += '</g></svg></div>';
 }

 this._container.innerHTML = xHTML;

 return this._container;
    }
});

L.insets = function () {
    return new L.Insets();
};
```